# Plumbing pipes with pipe() in c++

Tags: pipe, sorting, c++, fork

I am currently trying to connect pipes between a parent and its children. The children are execing `sort` and are sorting input they receive from the parent. The children then write to a separate pipe. There are two pipes for each process. One so the parent may send input to child. Another so the parent may receive the result of sort.

My problem thus far has been reading the input. I have been getting confirmation from `fputs()` that I am successfully writing to the childs input. After that I `fflush(NULL)` and try to read the child's output. The read blocks, as in it never returns or reaches a statement after `fputs`. Which is rather odd, as I believe that I have set the reads to `O_NONBLOCK`. The output is listed below.

```
line 174 
line 176 
line 178
```

Here is a snippet of code:

```
int sort_writes[num_sort][2];
    int sort_reads[num_sort][2];
    int i;
    int *status;
    int flags;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    // this should contain a bunch of write fds wrapped in fdopen
    FILE*  to_sort[num_sort];
    // the same except with reads
    FILE*  from_sort[num_sort];
    //this only include for simplicity and so that exec will happen proper
    char *sort_argv[2];
    sort_argv[0]=(char*)"sort";
    sort_argv[1]= (char *)NULL;

    // This will create all of the pipes for the sorts.
    // The parent will read  0 and the even pipes. it will write to the odd.
    for(i=0; i< num_sort; i++){
            //parent  reads from this pipe. child writes to it.
                    assert(pipe(sort_writes[i]) == 0);

            //parent write to this pipe. child reads from it.
                    assert(pipe(sort_reads[i]) ==0);
                    switch(fork()){
                            case 0: //this is the child
                                    //this closes unnecessary fds
                                    _close_less_than(i, sort_writes);
                                    _close_less_than(i, sort_reads);
                                    dup2(sort_reads[i][0], STDIN_FILENO);
                                    // standard out becomes parent pipe in
                                    dup2(sort_writes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                                                                                                   execv(SORT_LOC.c_str(), sort_argv);
                            default: // this the parent.
                                    //clean up. close unused.
                                    close(sort_writes[i][1]);
                                    close(sort_reads[i][0]);
                    }

    }
    //Creates a file pointer for all of the fds I will use to communicate with my sorts
    //It also sets all reads to nonblock and the parent write stdio buffers to zero.        
    for(i=0; i< num_sort; i++){
            assert((from_sort[i]= fdopen(sort_writes[i][0] ,"r")) != NULL);
            assert((to_sort[i]= fdopen(sort_reads[i][1] , "w")) != NULL);         //pipes ignore truncate

            flags = fcntl(sort_writes[i][0], F_GETFL);
            flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
            fcntl(sort_writes[i][0], F_SETFL, flags);


    }

    for(i=0; i<(int)theArray.size(); i++){
            fputs(theArray.back().c_str(), to_sort[i % num_sort]);
            theArray.pop_back();
            fflush(NULL); // so that the data gets from stdio buffers to pipe buffers.      
    }
    cout << "line 174 \n";
    for(i=0; i <1; i++){
            cout << "line 176 \n";
            while(!feof(from_sort[i])){
                    cout << "line 178 \n";
                    cout << fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, from_sort[i]);
                    cout << buffer;
                    cout << "at least i tried \n";
            }
```

Comment: The whole `dup2()` and `close()` problem is more complex than it seems at first glance.  See a [detailed discussion of pathological cases](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/remap-pipe-fds.html) and [complete sample code](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/remap-pipe-fds.c.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `dup2` and `close` before `exec`. With your code that way it is, `sort` has no idea which file descriptor to use for what. I don't know what `_close_less_than` does, but if it closes descriptors 0, 1, or 2, you're calling `sort` with an environment it cannot understand. You have to plumb your pipes to child's stdin and stdout.

Comment: I apologize for having wasted your time. I accidentally omitted those lines of my code while copying. The close less than function is function that iterates through and close all fds in the array with an index less than the passed int. Again thank you for your time. Regarding dup2, I believe what I am doing makes sense with the man pages. I want to replace the std in and out with the appropriate pipes yes?

Comment: Yes. Your example code is still missing `close` calls though. You need to close both ends of both pipes after your `dup2` calls. (Don't close the duplicated descriptors, of course.) Also, some programs won't work if they don't have a valid `stderr`. You can `open` `/dev/null` if needed.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I finally know why all my pipes have been failing. I ought the file descriptors from the arrays, the childs standards are pointing to the same file descriptions.  I will make sure to replace my standard error with NULL. Thanks again so much man. I spent a lot of time just not realizing that.